# Whiteboard interviews

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a Junior Ruby on Rails developer. In a few days I will be going to an interview and it will involve a whiteboard interview. What kind of questions will be asked? Will it just be about ROR? I heard it will also not just be able code but about thought processes, is this also true?

People who interview or have been through these to share their experience. Other information about the interviews people have been through would be a great help too.

Comment: How could we possibly know what will be asked? Off-topic anyway.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not programming.

Comment: Because I am asking people that do the interviews or have been through them what they have experienced.

Comment: Then search the web, there are dozens of resources. SO isn't one of then, though. And every company, every interviewer, has a different approach. Enumerating even a small subset of them isn't really what SO is designed for.

Comment: I have searched the web. I have witnessed many questions such as this on SO.

Comment: Search harder. Even a naive search yields pages of results for me, on a non-personalized engine.

Comment: If you've already read what I've found, what purpose would be served by sending it to you? To reiterate: we have no idea what kinds of questions will be asked. Here's a hint: if it's anything that can't be learned by rote,a few days isn't enough time to teach you how to think if you can't already. Not being able to find usable info isn't a good sign, though.

Comment: Try answering a few questions on StackOverflow as a warmup.

Comment: @Phlip Thank you for your suggestion. That is not a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the FB message.  Just got it.  Don't go there often, obviously,...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These are the only questions (and answers) I can remember from my interview

- who invented the white board? Ans: Martin Heit
- what were early whilte boards made of? Ans: film laminate
- who invented the dry erasable marker? Ans: Jerry Woolf
- which company makes a polyethylene terephthalate-on-steel whiteboard? Ans: PowerPet.

Hope that helps. (PS This answer will self-destruct in the not-too-distant future. [Edit: even though it's going to cost me points.  :-)] @user2687534: don't let the negative response get you down. Not "ice-breakers"; all just a feeble attempt at humour.)

Comment: I guess those were ice breaker questions. Thank you very much for your answer. I will not let the negative responses get me down.

Comment: This answer should self destruct now.

Comment: @zeantsoi, thanks for the reminder.  Egads, I just discovered one cannot delete an accepted answer.  Perhaps if a moderator sees this they can help.  I'll think twice the next time I feel mischievous,  but no guarantees.

Comment: @zeantsoi, I see you are a moderator.  Please sprinkle some magic dust on my answer to make it go away.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I don't have the moderator privileges required to remove an answer. I'm not particularly concerned with your answer – but others might be. You may want to consider that other users may downvote answers with questionable relevance in the future.

Comment: @zeantsoi, in posting answers, the possibility of attracting a downvoted is the last thing on my mind. 99.9% of the time I just post a straight answer, but if I can bring a smile to the face of anyone who shares my possibly offbeat sense of humour, without sidetracking the discussion, I will do so.  Usually I'll use a comment for that, but I chose an answer here because it was obvious the question was going nowhere, and would be flagged, and I thought it would allow the asker to laugh at him/herself, and not be discouraged be the negative comments. We need more humour at SO!

Comment: @CarySwoveland, suit yourself.